# What is the relationship between the "width" and "position" property of DIV?

Tags: html, css

```js
div1.innerHTML = "ab ab ab ab ab";
```

```css
#div0 {
        position: absolute;
    }

#div1 {
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="div0">    
    <div id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

The text in div1 will break at blanks. Div1 will be a block with narrow width and long height.

If div1's position is set to static, relative, or fixed, the div will stretch to fit the text's width.

I want to learn more about this behavior of DIV element.

Why "fixed" is different with "absolute" in this case, and this behavior is a standard? (I am particularly concerned about this question.)

UPDATE: 
I think I found the answer. I don’t set the width of the container of div1. The container is aboslute position. So its width is 0 and div1's width is also 0. If div1 is set to fixed, its parent will be window or viewport. Thus div1's width will be enough long.
[Code at Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLmvs96n/3/)

I did not describle the container in my origin question. Sorry.

PS: I worked with html/css for years. But There are always some simple, odd and surprising problems occur to me. Frustrating.

Comment: This is not enough code to go on. Putting this in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yzc386ew/2/) will not have the result you claim. So there must be more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im gonna consider this as a 2 part question the first the one with the actual code and the second how does the position property work. For the former, I think we need more code to understand your situation as for the second part,

The position property can have the following values,

**static**  Default value. Elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow
**absolute**    The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element
**fixed**   The element is positioned relative to the browser window
**relative**    The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20px" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position.

the difference between fixed and absolute is that absolute means the position of the element is set with regard to its ancestor elements. Usually, we give position:'relative' to the parent element and then we use postion: 'absolute' to define the position of the child element eg

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <img style="position: absolute, top:10px">
</div>
```

Here we set the position of the div first, then we set the image whose top will be 20px from the top of the parent div(ie its position is relative to the div)

Now with fixed the child element will have the position with respect to that of the browser, taking the same example

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <img style="position: fixed, margin-top:50px">
</div>
```

Now the image will be 50 from the top of the browser, regardless of where its parent div is. The parent could be at the bottom of the page but the div will always be 50px from the top of the page

So for absolute and fixed there is a chance the child can jump out of the parent container regardless of the parent container.